# Have I successfully created an ramfs drive?

Tags: linux, centos, tmpfs

I thought I had created a ramfs drive, but when I type `df -H` all I get is following.

```
Filesystem             Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5               69G   8.5G    57G  14% /
/dev/sdb3              2.8T   429G   2.3T  17% /home
/dev/sdb2               42G   6.8G    33G  18% /usr
/dev/sdb1               84G    12G    68G  15% /var
/dev/sda1              104M    37M    62M  38% /boot
/dev/sda3              1.1G   137M   853M  14% /tmp
tmpfs                  6.3G      0   6.3G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  537M   9.8M   528M   2% /var/spool/exim/db
tmpfs                  537M    25k   537M   1% /home/stuff/output
```

That is listing the tmpfs drives, but not the ramfs drives (I created 2 of them). Does this mean that they weren't successfully created, or do I have to use a different command to list them?

Comment: Well now I've found that they are listed if I type `mount`, but not from `ds`. What does that mean?

Comment: First of all I am not aware of any command called `ds`. Do you mean to say `df`?

Comment: Yes, sorry... I meant `df`

Comment: OK. Now can you post the steps you followed while creating and mounting the ram disk?

Comment: Like this: `mount -t ramfs -o size=500m ramfs /home/testing/output`

Comment: But actually it does give me this `ramfs on /home/testing/output type ramfs (rw,size=500m)` if I type `mount`. So maybe it is working..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested it on my system. I observed the same behavior. You are right the `ramfs` was successfully created and will work. You can view it using `df -a`.

After some reading  on the Internet to find the reason for this behavior. I have found that,

> For a ramfs filesystem, the newer kernels report nothing back using
>   "df". There is meant to be a patch for this (to allow for accounting
>   in a ramfs). Philosophically, ramfs is mean to be as simple as
>   possible, apparently, hence the lack of accounting. So data can be
>   stored and used on the ramfs disk, but no accounting of it is
>   possible, other than a loss of memory shown with "free". For this
>   reason the tmpfs is better, since it does keep accounting and "df"
>   shows what's going on.

There is a patch available for this. Google Keywords: **df ramfs patch**

You can find more information on Linux RAM-Based filesystems at the following link.

http://www.alper.net/linuxunix/linux-ram-based-filesystem/